# php mysqli result into an array not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have a php /mysqli query and I want to populate an array with the results:

```
$query3 ="SELECT * FROM conditions";
$results = array();
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query3)){    

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
       $results[] = $row;
     }
}
print_r($results);
```

Something is wrong here -its making arrays within arrays I think. (to be honest I am confused by this result)

How do I do this correctly!

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [condition_id] => 1 [condition_name] => Epilepsy )
    [1] => Array ( [condition_id] => 2 [condition_name] => ASD )
    [2] => Array ( [condition_id] => 3 [condition_name] => BESD )
    [3] => Array ( [condition_id] => 4 [condition_name] => HI )
    [4] => Array ( [condition_id] => 5 [condition_name] => Medical )
    [5] => Array ( ...
```

Thanks for all the help - now how should I create what I actually want which is one array with key=>value like this:

array (1=>epilepsy, 2=>ASd...) - the numbers refer to the primary key.

How do I populate an array from this query please?

Comment: `$results[] = $row;` You add each row to your array, so each subArray is one row from your db. Where is the problem ?

Comment: And what did/do you expect?

Comment: I think I was expecting something like 1=>Eplisey, 2=>ASD, 3=>BESD etc - just one array - the first starts at 1 not 0.

Comment: You have an array of rows 0-5 etc. and each row is an array of columns condition_id, etc.

Comment: @maxelcat  Edit your question. No need to write your codes in a comment

Comment: `$results[] = $row['condition_name'];`

Comment: `I think I was expecting something like...` - then how would a result set look like where each record has three, four, x fields?

Comment: thanks all - see where I am going wrong...

Comment: btw these -ve do annoy me. I am genuinely stuck here, trying to figure it out. I have been on it for ages. Its not like I haven't tried. You should mark laziness down, not genuine confusion.

Comment: `array_column($array, "condition_name","condition_id" ) ;`

Comment: @u_mulder That works except it `0` bases the array. If the OP wants it exactly as above, you'll need to `1` base the array or, better yet, let the returned result set control it `$result[$row['condition_id']] = $row['condition_name'];`...

Comment: yes War19ck 0 that's the way I did it in the end,

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
   $results[$row['condition_id']] = $row['condition_name'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move to PDO, Luke.

```
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT  FROM conditions")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
print_r($results);
```

Whoops! Is that all the code?